# How to create a mask in OpenCv4Android?

Tags: android, image, opencv

I want to create a mask in my coding,and I have a Rect and a input image,so how to initialize the mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mask normally is a CV_8U Mat.

1. Generate a CV_8U Mat
2. Draw on this Mat

This worked for me:

```
Mat mask = new Mat(src.size(), CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(0)); // This will contain the mask

Imgproc.rectangle(mask, point1, point2, new Scalar(1), Core.FILLED); // Draw on the mask
```

I hope it helps you :)